# Fazer um select e caso um campo específico esteja vazio fazer um join para buscar esse resultado em outro campo MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer uma consulta em uma tabela no mysql onde caso um campo especifico esteja vazio, quero que ela faça um join alterando o campo da busca para encontrar o resultado de outra tabela. Vou dar um exemplo

Eu tenho a tabela tb_produto onde tenho os campos: id, nome, valor, url_imagem, sku, sku_produto_pai.

Nessa tabela eu tenho as vezes produtos simples e com variações(cor, tamanho) então o campo url_imagem pode estar vazio porque a imagem está apenas no registro do produto pai.

Então caso o campo "url_imagem" na primeira busca sem filtros, esteja vazio quero que ele busque novamente nessa mesma tabela mas faça uma busca pelo campo sku = sku_produto_pai e pegue o campo "url_imagem", pois no pai estará preenchido.

Como posso montar esse selct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso, poderia fazer o join (`left` ou  `right` dependendo do lado) com a própria tabela, relacionando o sku com sku_produto_pai. Na prática, será um *self join*, ou seja, relacionar a tabela com ela mesma.

Isso vai fazer com que, quando o produto não for um "pai", ele deve ter o sku_produto_pai preenchido, e deve relacionar a linha com o "pai", assim sendo possível obter a url do registro "pai".

A seguir, basta usar a função [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) ou a função [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), que selecionam um valor não nulo entre uma lista de valores, o primeiro na ordem que forem informados. Como aqui temos apenas dois valores possíveis, o do próprio produto ou do pai, convém usar `IFNULL`, que aceita dois valores, pois `COALESCE` trabalha de forma semelhante, mas pode aceitar multiplos valores (mais de 2), o que não é o caso.

A query ficaria assim:

```
select distinct p.id, 
       p.nome,
       p.url_imagem,
       p.sku,
       p.sku_produto_pai,
       ifnull(p.url_imagem, ppai.url_imagem) imagem
 from tb_produto p
 left join tb_produto ppai on ppai.sku = p.sku_produto_pai;
```

Notas:

- foi usado `left join`, porque queremos todos os registros da tabela "à esquerda", que no caso é a primeira no `from`, e apenas os registros encontrados na tabela a seguir, que é a própria tabela "tb_produto" relacionada com o sku, e com o apelido de "ppai". Isso faz com que, quando não houver registro a relacionar, por exemplo quando o produto já o "pai" e ele tem a coluna "sku_produto_api" `NULL`, vai relacionar normalmente e retornar o null. Se usar um `inner join` o registro deve ter o valor igual nas duas colunas, e vai nesse caso não retornar os registros "pai", pois ele como tal, não devem ter valor na coluna "sky_produto_pai";
- foi usada a função `IFNULL` assim: `ifnull(p.url_imagem, ppai.url_imagem)`, ou seja, **tenta primeiro pegar a imagem do "próprio produto"**, tabela com apelido "p", **e se esse for vazio, pega do registro "pai"**, que vai estar com o apelido "ppai".

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6mSkMg1jGuHWUz1NGHViK/0)

Em resumo:

- relacionar a tabela com ela mesma através do campo necessário
- usar uma função que escolha entre os valores não nulos, sempre usando o campo da tabela "principal" no relacionamento primeiro.